# How to integrate / enable Centrify in a client web application

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, centrify

I need to use Centrify for SSO in cloud hosted application. I followed many forums(https://docs.centrify.com/en/centrify/appref/cloudhelp/gen/SAML_genericUserPassword.pdf) and couldn't get a clear picture what needs to be done.

I can create a application under custom apps with NTML authentication method enabled. But have no idea how my client application will consume this.

Please let me know what more details I need to share to get a help to integerate Centrify in my Application.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Nick and I am the Sr. Manager of Developer Relations and Product Management at Centrify.

The NTLM/Basic application type is a type of vaulting application that is supported by Centrify. This application vaults the users credentials from Centrify to an NTLM authentication box when it is presented by the protected web application. The application itself, or the applications web server, needs to be coded to make use of NTLM to authenticate to it. With this in place, when you manually navigate to the web application, you will see a popup asking for a username and password. Once the web application is set up in this way, the Centrify NTLM application will be able to detect the popup and vault the credentials to it. You can go here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx to learn how to set up IIS to use NTLM for authentication to a protected site.

If you need more help on this, please feel free to reach out to devsupport@centrify.com. We have dedicated developers available to assist you every step of the way with your project.

Thank you,

Nick Gamb